# Is it possible to say "to refund (an amount) to an order"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions

I sent a Customer a partial refund. I want to inform her using the verb `to refund` *+ a preposition*. Considering my native language, I would say

> I've just refunded $20 **to** your order.

According to my research the correct preposition is **for** ("I've just refunded $20 for your order").

Is it possible in principle to say "To **refund** (an amount) **to** an order" when it comes to a partial refund? And if not, can you please explain why? Well, I am trying to impose this construction to one I would use in my native language and it seems quite logical to me.

Comment: You would normally say you've refunded _to_ the source of the funding -- so "to your account", "to your credit card", etc. You could also say "I've refunded $20 in respect of your order", though that's quite a formal usage that always sounds a bit awkward to me.

Comment: @calum_b, thank you. This is exactly I wanted to know. If you spare a minute or two to post your comment in a form of answer, you will get some kudos.